# logical solution of trigonometry limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Most colculators say that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos x^\frac {2}{3} - 1}{x} = 0$, but how do we get to this? I tried to solve it the same way as we interpret $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos^2 x - 1}{x(\cos x+1)}=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin^2 x}{x(\cos x+1)}=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x}{x} \sin x \frac {1}{\cos x + 1}=0$, but in the end i got $-\infty * 0 * 1/2$. Looking for ideas guys.

Comment: Why $\infty$? The limit of $\sin x / x$  is known to be $1$.

Comment: @N74 yea, but we get $ \frac {\sin x^ \frac{2}{3}}{x} $ and it is not 1(

Comment: @N74 thats an example of similar solution i tried to use, but the real sample has $ x^ \frac {2}{3} $ and that's why we get different outcome

Comment: Ok, let's try to use it: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos x^{2 \over 3} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos^2 x^{2 \over 3} - 1}{x(\cos x^{2 \over 3} +1)}=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin^2 x^{2 \over 3} }{x(\cos x^{2 \over 3} +1)}=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x^{2 \over 3} }{x} \sin x^{2 \over 3} \frac {1}{\cos x^{2 \over 3} + 1}=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x^{2 \over 3} }{x^{2 \over 3}  } {\sin x^{2 \over 3} \over x^{2 \over 3} } x^{1 \over 3}  \frac {1}{\cos x^{2 \over 3} + 1}=0$

Comment: @N74 oh, man, i'm dumb:D Thanks a lot

Comment: Or, if you know that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x^{2/3})-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x^{2/3})-1}{x^{4/3}} \cdot x^{1/3} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} x^{1/3} = -\frac{1}{2} \cdot 0$ (where in the first limit we made the substitution $t=x^{2/3}$ - and for a complete solution, we need to argue that $x^{2/3} \ne 0$ whenever $x \ne 0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{2/3} = 0$ in order for the substitution to be valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same way.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}-1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}-1}{x}\cdot \frac{\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1}{\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1}$$

$$\implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^2 x^{\frac{2}{3}}-1}{x\big(\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}{+1}\big)} = -\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{x\big(\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}{+1}\big)} = -\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\cos x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1}$$

The latter limit tends to $0$.

Comment: true, but first limmit on the answer tends to $ \infty $, isn't it a problem?

Comment: could you explain it somehow? I'm still not sure

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

$$\cos^\frac 23(x)-1=\frac{-\sin^2(x)}{\cos^\frac 43(x) +\cos^\frac 23(x)+1}$$

the limit is $\frac 03$=zero.

Comment: that seems nice, but I have $x^ \frac{2}{3}$, not $\cos^ \frac{2}{3}$, sorry if it's not clear